# Find overlapping intervals in groups and retain largest non-overlapping periods

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

**Issue**
I have a grouped dataframe with overlapping intervals (date as ymd). I want to retain only the largest non-overlapping intervals in each group.

**Example data**

```
# Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Example data
df <- tibble(
  group = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
  start = as_date(
    c("2019-01-10", "2019-02-01", "2019-10-05", "2018-07-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-30","2019-11-20")),
  end = as_date(
    c("2019-02-07", "2019-05-01", "2019-11-15", "2018-07-31", "2019-05-05", "2019-11-06", "2019-10-07", "2019-12-10","2019-12-31"))) %>%
  mutate(intval = interval(start, end),
         intval_length = intval / days(1))

df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#>   group start      end        intval                         intval_length
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                             <dbl>
#> 1     1 2019-01-10 2019-02-07 2019-01-10 UTC--2019-02-07 UTC            28
#> 2     1 2019-02-01 2019-05-01 2019-02-01 UTC--2019-05-01 UTC            89
#> 3     1 2019-10-05 2019-11-15 2019-10-05 UTC--2019-11-15 UTC            41
#> 4     2 2018-07-01 2018-07-31 2018-07-01 UTC--2018-07-31 UTC            30
#> 5     2 2019-01-01 2019-05-05 2019-01-01 UTC--2019-05-05 UTC           124
#> 6     3 2019-10-01 2019-11-06 2019-10-01 UTC--2019-11-06 UTC            36
#> 7     3 2019-10-01 2019-10-07 2019-10-01 UTC--2019-10-07 UTC             6
#> 8     3 2019-11-30 2019-12-10 2019-11-30 UTC--2019-12-10 UTC            10
#> 9     3 2019-11-20 2019-12-31 2019-11-20 UTC--2019-12-31 UTC            41

# Goal
# Row: 1 and 2; 6 to 9 have overlaps; Keep rows with largest intervals (in days)
df1 <- df[-c(1, 7, 8),]

df1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   group start      end        intval                         intval_length
#>   <dbl> <date>     <date>     <Interval>                             <dbl>
#> 1     1 2019-02-01 2019-05-01 2019-02-01 UTC--2019-05-01 UTC            89
#> 2     1 2019-10-05 2019-11-15 2019-10-05 UTC--2019-11-15 UTC            41
#> 3     2 2018-07-01 2018-07-31 2018-07-01 UTC--2018-07-31 UTC            30
#> 4     2 2019-01-01 2019-05-05 2019-01-01 UTC--2019-05-05 UTC           124
#> 5     3 2019-10-01 2019-11-06 2019-10-01 UTC--2019-11-06 UTC            36
#> 6     3 2019-11-20 2019-12-31 2019-11-20 UTC--2019-12-31 UTC            41
```

**Current approach**
I found a related question in another thread (see: [Find dates within a period interval by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200364/find-dates-within-a-period-interval-by-group)). However, the respective solution identifies all overlapping rows by group. In this way, I can't identify the largest non-overlapping intervals.

```
df$overlap <- unlist(tapply(df$intval, #loop through intervals
                            df$group,  #grouped by id
                            function(x) rowSums(outer(x,x,int_overlaps)) > 1))
```

As an example, consider group 3 in my example data. Here row 6/7 and 8/9 overlap. With row 6 and 9 being the largest non-overlapping periods, I would like to remove row 7 and 8.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could pinpoint me to a solution.

Comment: This looks non-trivial.  If your data are not too big you could brute-force it.  Otherwise, you need an algorithm.  This isn't really an R question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having searched for related problems on stackoverflow, I found that the following approaches (here: [Collapse and merge overlapping time intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213418/collapse-and-merge-overlapping-time-intervals)) and (here: [How to flatten / merge overlapping time periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694)) could be adapted to my issue.

```
# Solution adapted from:
# here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53213418/collapse-and-merge-overlapping-time-intervals
# and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28938147/how-to-flatten-merge-overlapping-time-periods/28938694#28938694 

# Note: df and df1 created in the initial reprex (above)

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  arrange(group, start) %>%
  mutate(indx = c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(lead(start))  >            # find overlaps
                              cummax(as.numeric(end)))[-n()])) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(group, indx) %>%
  arrange(desc(intval_length)) %>%                                # retain largest interval
  filter(row_number() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-indx) %>%
  arrange(group, start)

# Desired output?
identical(df1, df2)
#> [1] TRUE
```